# set a date column in sql based on a another column

Tags: sql, sql-update, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have a SQL Table with two columns:

```
Col1      Col2
202205    NULL
202204    NULL
202103    NULL
```

Now I want to set the Date in Col2 based on the value of Col1. So the result
should look like this:

```
Col1    Col2
202205  2022-05-01
202204  2022-04-01
202103  2021-03-01
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Col1` be text, we can try using the `TO_DATE` function here:

```sql
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '202205' AS Col1
)

SELECT TO_DATE(Col1 || '01', 'YYYYMMDD') AS Col2  -- 2022-05-01
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: No need to concat '01' at the end. If you do `TO_DATE(Col1, 'YYYYMM')`, it will automatically output '2022-05-01'.

Comment: @AleixCC Just learned something new from you.  But in general, if the OP wanted the dates to fall on some _other_ day, then we would still have to concatenate on that day.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL:

```
UPDATE  test_tbl
SET Col2 = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(Col1,'','01') ,'%Y%m%d');
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u5QHnbL3ye2rkC6HdxJpqV/1)

Answer (score 0):

create or replace table Conv(col1 number,col2 number);

insert into Conv values (202205,NULL),(202204,NULL),(202103,NULL);

select Col1,TO_DATE(Col1 || '01', 'YYYYMMDD') AS Col2 from Conv;